# Customising MySql table values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql, the table has 3 fields (name, date, number). The table connected to my app via PHP.

What I need is to make MySql to accept only English numbers. I don't want to do it via PHP, is there any way to do it in MySql to restrict it from accepting such as (Arabic, Parisian).

If there's any options can I do it from MySql.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that easily with a regex,

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-9]*$';
```

**Edit :** If your goal is only to block Arabic text, then here a regex that would select only `ASCII` character from the space to the tild(0-127).

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable where number REGEXP '^[ -~]*$'
```

Comment: I don't want to select only English numbers, but I need to restrict users to enter Arabic numbers. Can i change any option in MySql

Comment: "*What I need is to make MySql to accept only English numbers*", by the way they are not called English numbers. And no, I don't think there is any option for that, but why would you want to block them ?